# Working with formula's

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I'm creating a revision timetable in excel with drop down menus for each subject but I wanted to have a separate table to show how many hours of each subject I've revised for. What formula could I use to do this and how would I structure the formula?

Thanks

Dylan

Comment: Can you provide a brief sample of the data as it is currently laid out?

Comment: @BryanC http://i.stack.imgur.com/a32nR.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is `COUNTIF`

```
=COUNTIF(B3:E9,"History")
```

or, if you were to put your subjects in column K, you could reference them directly so you can copy paste your formula down.

```
=COUNTIF(B3:E9,K1)
```

Where K1 is the cell with a subject name in it.

Comment: Thanks, really helped! Can get on with my revision now!